# Loop for, strange outcome

Tags: java

I'm learning Java with the book "Java: A Beginner's Guide".
The book shows this example of the for loop:

```
// Loop until an S is typed
class ForTest {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {

        int i;

        System.out.println ("Press S to stop.");

        for (i=0; (char) System.in.read() != 'S'; i++)
                System.out.println ("Pass #" + i);
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Press S to stop.
s
Pass #0
Pass #1
Pass #2
d
Pass #3
Pass #4
Pass #5
S
```

I do not understand why it writes three times Pass #  each time I press a different keyboard key to S.
I think it should write Pass # only once.
Thank you.

Comment: Don't put control characters to the stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pressed `s` and then return. That "return" generated two more characters - `\r` and `\n` (I assume you're on Windows). Those are then returned by `System.in.read()`.

Here's an example which makes that clearer:

```
class ForTest {
    public static void main (String args[]) throws java.io.IOException {

        int i;

        System.out.println ("Press S to stop.");
        char c;
        for (i = 0; (c = (char) System.in.read()) != 'S'; i++) {
            System.out.println ("Pass #" + i + "; c=" + (int) c);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Press S to stop.
a
Pass #0; c=97
Pass #1; c=13
Pass #2; c=10
b
Pass #3; c=98
Pass #4; c=13
Pass #5; c=10
S
```

`\r` is Unicode character 13, and `\n` is 10.